# Read xml response data from ebay categories api

Tags: xml, response, categories, ebay-api

I am getting response ebay categories data in `XML` format so I can't read xml response.It returns many categories and its sub levels.How can I read xml response ? Any trick ?

```
<?php 
       $app_id="xxxxxxx";
       $dev_id ="xxxxxxx";
       $cert_id="xxxxxxx";
       $call_name="GetCategoryInfoRequest";
       $token="xxxxxxxx";
       $site_id = 0;
       $compat_level=819;

    $endpoint = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";



        $headers = array(
            'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 819',
            'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: '.$dev_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: '.$app_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '.$cert_id,
            'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetCategories',
            'X-EBAY-API-OPERATION-NAME: GetCategories',
            'X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING:JSON',
            'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0',
            'Content-Type:text/XML'
        );

        $xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
        $xmlRequest .= "<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
        $xmlRequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>";
        $xmlRequest .= "<eBayAuthToken>{$token}</eBayAuthToken>";
        $xmlRequest .= "</RequesterCredentials>";
        $xmlRequest .= "<CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>";
        $xmlRequest .= "<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>";
        $xmlRequest .= "</GetCategoriesRequest>";



$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400000);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
print_r($response);
?>
```

It returns unformatted number of lines,check below ebay categories `XML` response data

> 2015-09-09T10:24:56.505ZSuccess933E933_CORE_APICATALOG_17621198_R1truetrue200811Antiques20081truetrue379032Antiquities20081truetrue379083The
>   Americas37903truetruetrue1629223Byzantine37903truetruetrue1629233Celtic37903truetruetrue379053Egyptian37903truetruetrue1629163Far
>   Eastern37903truetruetrue379063Greek37903truetruetrue1629173Holy
>   Land37903truetruetrue1629183Islamic37903truetruetrue911013Near
>   Eastern37903truetruetrue668343Neolithic &
>   Paleolithic37903truetruetrue379073Roman37903truetruetrue1629193South
>   Italian37903truetruetrue1629203Viking37903truetruetrue1629213Reproductions37903truetruetrue1711693Price
>   Guides & Publications37903truetruetrue734643Other
>   Antiquities37903truetruetrue47072Architectural &
>   Garden20081truetrue1629253Balusters4707truetruetrue1629263Barn
>   Doors4707truetruetrue1629273Beams4707truetruetrue379093Ceiling
>   Tins4707truetruetrue635163Chandeliers, Fixtures,
>   Sconces4707truetruetrue1629283Columns &
>   Posts4707truetruetrue1629293Corbels4707truetruetrue379103Doors4707truetruetrue635173Finials4707truetruetrue635183Fireplaces
>   &
>   Mantels4707truetruetrue47083Garden4707truetruetrue379113Hardware4707truetrue379124Door
>   Bells & Knockers37911truetruetrue379144Door Knobs &
>   Handles37911truetruetrue379164Door Plates &
>   Backplates37911truetruetrue1629334Drawer
>   Pulls37911truetruetrue1629344Escutcheons & Key Hole
>   Covers37911truetruetrue1629354Heating Grates &
>   Vents37911truetruetrue379134Hooks &
>   Brackets37911truetruetrue379154Locks & Keys37911truetruetrue1629304

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing -- and mixing code between -- 2 different eBay API calls:

- [GetCategoryInfo](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetCategoryInfo.html) (Shopping API family)
- [GetCategories](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetCategories.html) (Trading API family)

Unless you have a special need for using the Trading API, I recommend selecting GetCategoryInfo and using that call. You won't need to POST headers and can instead build all your parameters in a REST/GET request.

Comment: I have updated my code.If  I use GetCategoryInfo(Shopping API) it returns only one level of category not all categories in one time call but in getCategories(Trading API) I can get all categries level in one time call